# Java: How does a method operate on objects of unknown type?

Tags: java, class, methods, import

Consider, the following three Java classes in three different packages:

**User.java**

```
package user;

public class User {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

**UserFactory.java**

```
package factory;

import user.User;

public class UserFactory {

    private static User user;

    public static User getUser() {
        if (user == null) {
            user = new User();
        }
        return user;
    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```
package test;

import factory.UserFactory;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserFactory.getUser().setName("StackOverflow");
        System.out.println(UserFactory.getUser());
    }
}
```

The main method belongs to class `test.Test` that doesn't import `user.User` class. However, it is able to operate on `user.User` type.

How to justify this behaviour?

Comment: This has been answered at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785868/why-is-import-of-class-not-needed-when-calling-method-on-instance-java>

Comment: Side note; unrelated to your question: A) your factory is probably "wrong"; there is no point in having **one static** user object. Most programmers would assume that a call to a **factory** class gives them a new user each time.

Comment: @Dhananjay - Thanks for the link. I tried searching for similar questions, but couldn't find one.

Comment: @GhostCat - Accepted. This is just a sample code to support my question, not a real factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *only* purpose of an `import` statement is to allow you to use a type (or a method etc, for `import static`) without fully-specifying the name. It doesn't make the type available - it just makes it available by short name.

In this case, the `UserFactory` type is imported, and the compiler knows the exact type returned by `UserFactory.getUser()`... that type doesn't need to be *named* in the code that calls `getUser()`.

If you wanted to write:

```
User u = UserFactory.getUser();
```

*then* you'd need the import... or you could just fully-qualify it:

```
user.User u = UserFactory.getUser();
```

But unless you need to refer to the type by short name within the source code, there's no need for an import statement.